# Android taking images without preview using new "Camera2" api

Tags: android, android-camera

I am new to Android, i want to take pictures in background without surface view/preview. I have searched online but the methods don't seem working for me. I want to use the latest Camera2 API.

Regards!
Muhammad Awais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an ImageReader, and a camera capture session with that ImageReader's Surface.  No need to have a SurfaceView or TextureView as well.

You'll need to stream some number of captures before starting to save any, though, to ensure that the auto-exposure/focus/etc routines of the camera have time to converge.